# libav - readability of text from high resolution to low viewing resolution

Tags: libav

Scenario: Trying to create a screencast of a linux system for a tutorial.. The two monitors I have are a combined (3400x1200).. When I play it back on a windows machine, either using VLC or Windows Media Player on a 1920x1020 screen, the terminal font is unreadable.

What is the best way to ensure that the video is able to play on all screen sizes such that the font is legible at say at a 1920x1200 resolution?

Notes:

- I must record on both screens, as my tutorial spans across two monitors and must have entire screen size, I can do with the first screen, and half the second.
- I have read about anti-aliasing but not sure if that is what is right for me, or perhaps even a good way to apply it. Are there base yum packages I can install and use?
- I am encoding in x264 and outputting to .avi
- Here is the command I am using to initiate the recording: `avconv -f x11grab -r 25 -s 1600x900 -i :0.0 -vcodec libx264 -threads 4 ~/Desktop/output.avi`

Thank you for your help and guidance